# How to create external link in classic ASP using web address from a database

Tags: asp-classic, hyperlink

I am working on a classic ASP project and I am having a problem creating a link to an outside website.  I am pulling data from an existing database and displaying it in a table using ASP and one of the pieces of data I am showing in a table is a URL to a company's website.  I need to be able to click on the website URL and have it take me to the proper website.

Currently I am using a standard href which usually works fine for me but in this case it ends up trying to link me to an internal page.

Physical Path it is trying: C:\inetpub\Project1\www.companyurl.com

I need it to just go to: www.companyurl.com

Here is the code I am currently using for the link:

```
 <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap><font face="Verdana" size="1"><b><a href="<%= rsCompInfo ("company_website") %>" target="<%= rsCompInfo("Company_Website") %>"> <%= rsCompInfo("Company_Website") %> </a></b></font>&nbsp;</td>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If address doesn't start with http:// you have to explicitly add it. Try ;

```
 <%= "http://" & rsCompInfo("company_website") %>
```